# Trying to use symbols withing the number in the siunitx package

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I'm trying to use the following with [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

```
\omega_x = \SI{100\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}
```

But it comes out wrong. There is a space placed between 10 and 0π, as if π
 was actually a digit rather than a symbol. How do I get `siunitx` to treat it as a symbol?

I'd prefer an option to be used with the `\usepackage` declaration, to make the behaviour system-wide. An alternative package would also be helpful.

Image for clarification:

[image: siunitx output, with superfluous space between the zeros]

Also, I'd prefer a way that supported multiple symbols. I'm using the TeX Live 2012 distribution, last updated on September 25, if that helps.

Comment: Would `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{100\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}` help? See section 5.4 of the documentation.

Comment: @egreg It would, in this case, but unfortunately it wouldn't work the way I want in the case of `\SI{1000\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}`, for example.

Comment: I found [this](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-01/msg00824.html) thread, but nothing it it seems to work. Also, the `input-symbols` option (page 20-21 of the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf)) lists a default value of `\pi\dots`, but even so, manually setting it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: What would you want in the case of `1000\pi`?

Comment: A spacing between the rendering of `1` and `000\pi`. To my understanding, `parse-numbers=false` eliminates all automatic spacing in the numbers section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things I'd suggest:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pii}{\ensuremath{\pi}}
\newcommand*{\customSI}[4][]{\num[#1]{#2}#3\,\si[#1]{#4}} % \, should be substituted for siunitx' inter-unit-product
\newcommand*{\customSIcustom}[4][]{\SI[parse-numbers=false,#1]{\num[parse-numbers=true,#1]{#2}#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}
\(\omega_x = \SI[parse-numbers=false]{\num[parse-numbers=true]{10000}\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}\)\\
\(\omega_x = \customSIcustom{10000}{\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}\)\\
\(\omega_x = \customSI{10000}{\pi}{rad.s^{-1}}\)\\
\(\omega_x = \SI{10000}{\pii.rad.s^{-1}}\)\\
\(\omega_x = \SI[number-unit-product={}]{10000}{\pii.rad.s^{-1}}\)
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: updated]

Comment: The `customSI` option is perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: However, I prefer defining a command for the first option. For anyone wanting to do this, I suspect `\newcommand*{\customSI}[4][]{\SI[parse-numbers=false,#1]{\num[parse-numbers=true]{#2}#3}{#4}}` would do it.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi I've updated my answer. Take a look at `\customSIcustom` (and choose a more appropriate name).

Comment: @HameerAbbasi It works in my MWE. Maybe a conflicting package? You can also issue `#1` to the inner `\num`.

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work anymore. `\newcommand*{\customSIcustom}[4][]{\SI[parse-numbers=false,#1]{\num[parse-numbers=true,#1]{#2}#3}{#4}}` treats everything as `parse-numbers=false`
I'm only using the standard `ams*` and `inputenc` packages.

Comment: But, to be fair, I'm re-installing all of TeX Live, so that may be causing the issue.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Are you sure? Numbers < 10000 are per default not typeset with a thousand marker (`\,`, `.`, `.` depending on the setting.) Those options start with `group-`.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, this answer works again.