# Typeset diameter symbol with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I'm currently trying to display diameter dimensions with `siunitx`.

There is an old discussion with something similar in [Trying to use symbols withing the number in the siunitx package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74606/trying-to-use-symbols-withing-the-number-in-the-siunitx-package).
Also, in [Automatically spacing the tilde (~) symbol as a prefix number using the `siunitx` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162145/automatically-spacing-the-tilde-symbol-as-a-prefix-number-using-the-siunitx) a patch is proposed to typeset number prefixes, though it seems it does not work with the current version of siunitx.

I thought the `input-signs` option of `siunitx` could help to handle that kind of situation, but I can't figure how to leverage this.

One could imagine that typing `\SI{d10}{\milli\meter}` would be output as `$\diameter$~\SI{10}{\milli\meter}`.

Is it possible to patch `siunitx` to support this ?

Comment: Sorry but the diameter symbol isn't part of the value here at all: what's wrong with `$\diameter = \qty{10}{\mm}$` or similar?

Comment: @JosephWright yes, it's not part of the value, but its sort of a number prefix like for $ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81673/141947. There is nothing wrong with what you propose, except the `=` sign

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst it feels odd to me, if you feel the diameter symbol is 'comparator-like' then

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\robustify\diameter
\sisetup{input-comparators = \diameter}
\begin{document}
$\qty{\diameter10}{\mm}$
\end{document}
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted !